# Is it possible to run dask/distributed jobs on the certain workers list

Tags: python, distributed, dask

I have a computation network with 40 workers, but I need to perform calculations only on certain hosts. Is it possible to limit or rebuild network for using only specified workers?

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's difficult to tell what you're looking for beyond a yes/no answer. Please see [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify particular workers with the `workers=` keyword to client.submit, client.map, client.compute, or client.persist.

```
futures = client.map(func, args, workers=['worker-1', 'worker-2'])
```

See http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locality.html#user-control
 for more options

You can also register resources like GPUs with the workers and restrict computations to those.  See http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html for more information.

Comment: it helps to limit the workers list, but I have a strange situation. I have 4 workers in test, 10 tasks for computation, but only two random workers are selected for computation. On other computation another two random workers are selected.

Comment: I found the root cause of the partial workers selection. I've scattered some data to the workers:

Comment: I found the root cause of the partial workers selection. I've scattered some data to the workers:

`client.scatter({'config': {}, 'data': {}}, workers=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`

And as result I had data scattered partially and only on two workers:

`{'tcp://a': ['config'], 'tcp://b': ['data']}`

When I used broadcast I had required data on all workers and all of them was used in the computation:
`client.scatter({'config': {}, 'data': {}}, workers=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],        broadcast=True)`